# How many FPS is good for a non gaming iphone app?

Tags: iphone, performance, xcode-instruments

I tested my app with instruments:
[image]

When scrolling table views, it's around 20-50 fps, (more like 25 average). Is that good enough? I've reused the table view cells and did quite a lot of optimisations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slow frame rates are like pornography - hard to define but you know it when you see it.

In other words, worry about the feel, not the numbers. If it feels laggy, it is.

Answer (score 0):

20-50 is great.  Television has a frame rate around 30, and movies sometimes have frame rates as low as 24.  For non gaming situations you can do just fine going as low as 15.  Rates lower than that will start to feel laggy.